# Transferring database from Firebase to Mongodb issue?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

on Firebase i used to have tree like structure example of which is

```
city: {
     "name":"abc"
      "details1" : {
              "abc" : {
                     "aa" : "bb"
               }
       }

       "details2" : {
              "abc" : {
                     "aa" : "bb"
               }
       }


}
```

So i used to call nested foreach functions like snapshot, childsnapshot, childchildsnapshot to get to the last value and publish the key Ind value.

But on MongoDB cursor only goes for one level. so i am not able to understand how can I print only those key which has further subsets of key, value.

I only want to print details1 and details2

Expected output should be key: details1 and details2.

Comment: could you post the expected output

Comment: the output i want is all the child key who have sub child that is details1 and details2

Comment: Please post the json output by editing your question